# AngularJS - get DB data(in js) / use ng-show(in html)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I am trying to get date from my db. And with the data I wanna use ng-show.

In my js file :

```
 httpq.post('/data/instructor.asmx/PasswordAgain', postData)
        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.informs = JSON.parse(data.d.result).Table;

            if ($scope.informs.length > 0) {
                $scope.Ins_Checking = $scope.informs[0];
            }

        })
        .catch(function(data, status) {
            $.showToast('error', $filter('translate')('MSG.ERROR'));
        })
        .finally(function() {
            console.log("finally finished1");
        });
```

In my html file(Test Code):

```
<div ng-repeat="inform in informs">
  {{inform.Ins_Check}}
</div>
```

This is working.

Question :

```
<div ng-show="Ins_Check != 'O'">
    Input Password : <input type="password">
</div>
<div ng-show="Ins_Check == 'O'">
    The password is Correct!
</div>
```

With the DB data(inform.Ins_Check), If the data is not 'O', show Input Password code. Or if the data is 'O', show the words 'The password is Correct!'.

What code should I input?

Or should I use another function?

Comment: What is not working? Why don't you have an else clause?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$scope.Ins_Checking = $scope.informs.length ? $scope.informs[0].Ins_Check: 'O';`?

Comment: $scope.Ins_Checking = $scope.informs.length ? $scope.informs[0].Ins_Check: 'O'; << this is working too. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-show` and `ng-hide` are worked on truthy and falsy values. if `Ins_Check` has     Boolean value then you do not need to compare with 0 or 1. Simple write `ng-show="Ins_Check"` and `ng-hide="!Ins_Check"`

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Ex6HoThDC2xDPK9ujX1?p=preview)

Comment: Please always add the code to your answer not only a link to plnkr

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I got the data 'O' or 'X' from db. So I modify the code like this.  `<div ng-show="inform.Ins_Check == 'X'" ng-repeat="inform in informs"> <div ng-show="inform.Ins_Check == 'O'" ng-repeat="inform in informs">`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay response.

The code that you are using is the right one for ng-show. The condition variable that you are checking is wrong.

In your js, you have used  `$scope.Ins_Checking` for assigning the value. But in the ng-show comparison, you are using `Ins_Check` which is not available with your example.

So try with replacing `Ins_Check` with `Ins_Checking`. I hope this works.